# Given characteristic function $\phi(t) = e^{-|t|^{a}/a}$, where a is some constant

Tags: probability-theory, fourier-transform, central-limit-theorem, characteristic-functions

I was wondering about the following question:

I am given a family of distributions whose characteristic functions are of the form $\phi(t) = e^{-|t|^{a}/a}$, where a is some constant. We want to find out what values can a have such that a distribution can exist.

Notice that

- In the case of a = 2, $e^{-|t|^{2}/2}$ is the characteristic function of a standard normal.
- In the case of a = 1, $e^{-|t|}$ is the characteristic function of a standard Cauchy.

What I noticed is that using [inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae), we know the characteristic function $\phi(t)$ must be such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\phi(t)| dt < \infty$. This is not true here for a $\leq 0$.

However, I wonder if the inversion formula tells me more than this about what values a can take, or is it just a formula telling me how to compute the density function from a characteristic function so long as the preconditions are met (which is true for a $>0$ I believe).

Any comment / ideas / discussions are welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think Polya's theorem (see bottom of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Criteria_for_characteristic_functions ) says your $\phi$ is a characteristic function if $0<a\le1$.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. What about the standard normal being a = 2 case? That's still valid but outside the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These characteristic functions are well known. $\phi (t)$ is a characteristic function iff $0<a \leq 2$. For $a=2$ we get the normal distribution and for $0<a<2$ we get a so-called (symmetric) stable distribution. $a=1$ gives a multiple of a Cauchy random variable. You can search Wikipedia for a discussion of stable distributions.

Comment: I found an article explaining this. Thanks a lot for the direction.